# SQL Server truncating encrypted values

Tags: sql-server

I'm having an issue with SQL Server truncating encrypted values.  It seems very strange as the length of the string it's encrypting isn't long at all.

If I execute the following SQL in a query window:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymmetricKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate; 

SELECT 
CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(
ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MySymmetricKey'), convert(varbinary(8000), cast('hellothisisastringwhichisntverylong' AS nvarchar(max))))
))
```

the output is: "hellothisisastringwhichisntver"

I've looked through lots of examples, however I can't see what I'm doing wrong?

I should point out also that I have tried variations of not using nvarchar(max) and varbinary(8000) and they don't change the outcome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CONVERT statement is not specifying the NVARCHAR length to use so it's using the default NVARCHAR(30)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx

Try this instead (or whatever other length you want):

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MySymmetricKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate; 

SELECT 
CONVERT(nvarchar(100), DecryptByKey(
ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MySymmetricKey'), convert(varbinary(8000), cast('hellothisisastringwhichisntverylong' AS nvarchar(max))))
))
```